# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnum' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am defining variables like below

```
self._demo.create_new_service(
            service_name=self._DATABASE_SERVICE,
            instance_name=self.database_name.lower()+'-pg-'+str(cnum),
            team_name=self.team,
            tenant_name=self.tenant,...............
```

But getting error

```
instance_name=self.database_name.lower()+'-pg-'+str(cnum),
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnum' referenced before assignment
```

Can someone help what I am missing here

Comment: where is your `cnum` initialized?

Comment: you are calling `+str(cnum)` before `cnum` is assigned a value. Therefore the error of `cnum referenced before assignment`.

Comment: I have already defined cnum above that function

cnum = max([int(instance.name.split('-')[-1]) \
                         for instance in self._demo.get_instances\
                         (service_name=self._DATABASE_SERVICE) if '-pg' in instance.name])+1

Comment: You have not included nearly enough code to diagnose, thereby forcing us to guess.  My guess is that you have created `cnum` as a global, and your function modifies `cnum` after this point.  In that case, unless you specify `global cnum` in the function, Python assumes it is a function-local variable throughout the entire function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Before posting, make sure - by trying it yourself - that someone else could **copy and paste** the code in the question **without adding or changing anything** and see the **exact problem, directly**.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you are seeing indicates that the variable 'cnum' has not been defined or assigned a value before it is being used in the expression self.database_name.lower()+'-pg-'+str(cnum).

You should make sure that the variable 'cnum' is defined and assigned a value before you use it in your code. One way to do this is to define and initialize the variable 'cnum' before calling the create_new_service method, like so:

```
cnum = 123 # Replace with the desired value for cnum
self._demo.create_new_service(
            service_name=self._DATABASE_SERVICE,
            instance_name=self.database_name.lower()+'-pg-'+str(cnum),
            team_name=self.team,
            tenant_name=self.tenant,...............
```

Make sure to replace the value 123 with the appropriate value for your use case. This should resolve the `UnboundLocalError` that you are seeing.